# Checking Database Server Status with Java

Tags: java, database, sockets, status

I want to check the online/offline status about a Database Server with Java.

Can I check this with a Socket connection over the port? I want to do this wihtout a Database connection with jdbc because the login and Database system info is unknown.

Comment: telnet to the server.

Comment: Not sure how this question is too broad to be covered here.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza People seem to be going ham on the close question these days.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
    try {
        Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", port);  //Port dependent on your DB/Server
        // Server is up
        socket.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        // Server is down
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can just open a `Socket` to the address and port of your databse server, if you get an `IOException` the server is down. (tested with postgress)

```
public boolean isDatabaseOnline(String address, int port) {
    boolean result;

    try {
        Socket socket = new Socket(address, port);
        socket.close();

        result = true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        result = false;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The above approaches don't really consider timing out in case the remote is unreachable, and a reasonable timeout should be defined because the default value is 20 seconds!!

You can state a timeout using the [`socket.connect`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#connect(java.net.SocketAddress,%20int)) method AFTER you create a blank socket.

```
SocketFactory sf = SocketFactory.getDefault();

try (Socket socket = sf.createSocket()) {
    socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ipAdder, port), timeoutInMillis);
    logger.info("database is up");
} catch (IOException e) {
    logger.info("database is down");
}
```

The example above uses [try with resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)